# Error in fitting model and input_shape with keras ConvNet

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

Would appreciate a tip or two from those of you who are experienced with keras. This is my first rodeo, and the bronco is bucking mightily!

I have pre-processed lung images and extracted 48x48x48mm cubic arrays representing pixels in regions of interest (dtype=uint8). I have stored these 8504 cubes in *.npy files.

When I pass a list of the cubes to the model as training data, I encounter the following error:

"Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 8504 arrays".

What might I be doing wrong?

The relevant code:

```
# input layer of model
c3d_model.add(Convolution3D(64, 8,8,8, activation='relu', border_mode='same',
              name='conv1', input_shape=(48, 48, 48, 1)))
# other layers ....

# get_data()
cubes = [np.load(os.path.join(CUBES_DIR, cubefile)) for cubefile in cubefiles] # cubefiles is a list of 8504 filenames

# shuffle data and labels to avoid skewing the training
ix = [i for i in range(len(labels))]
shuffle(ix)
X_cubes = [cubes[i] for i in ix]
Y_labels = [labels[i] for i in ix]

# and here's where I run aground
model.fit(cubes, Y_labels, validation_split=0.30, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=32, callbacks=[save_weights], verbose=2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says Keras expects an array, but you give it a list of arrays.

After shuffling, try:

```
X_cubes = np.array(X_cubes)
Y_labels = np.array(X_cubes)
```

Also note you are shuffling `X` and `Y` but only give the shuffled `Y` to Keras and the *unshuffled* `X`. I assume this is not what you intended.

Comment: Hi @vega, you got me past that error, thanks! And yes, passing the unshuffled X was a mistake. But now I'm seeing a different error after passing X_cubes as a numpy array:
_ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected convolution3d_input_14 to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (8504, 1)._ Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yes, your input is the wrong shape. if you type `cubes[0].shape`, what does it say? How is the data formatted in the file you are loading from? You need to know this so that you know how to shape the data properly for the network.

Comment: cubes[0].shape == (48, 48, 48) - Appreciate the help, @vega!

Comment: you have declared the convolution input as input_shape=(48, 48, 48, 1), whereas your input is (48, 48, 48), one less dimension. These should match. And if you do `cubes.shape`, you get (8504,48, 48, 48)?

Comment: I have found that, with 10 samples, `np.array(cubes).shape == (10,48,48,48)`. But with 11 samples (or more), `np.array(cubes).shape = (11,)`. Thus I am writing a generator that will yield 10 samples at a time; will post a comment if I can get it to work. As for the extra dimension, my understanding is that a 3D convolution expects 5 dimension (samples, rows, columns, depth, channels), which is why I provided the 1 at the end (designating 1 channel). IIRC I have seen sample code that designates a final dimension of 1 for gray-scale images, which is what I am working with. Again, thx @vega !

Comment: Ok no worries. I suspect maybe some samples are not exactly (48,48,48), maybe you have a (48,48,47) or something like that. In that case numpy cannot create a full array since the dimensions don't all match up. I suggest you loop through cubes `for i in len(cubes): if cubes[i].shape != (48,48,48): print("bad dimensions with sample ",str(i))`, to check which example is wrong. I hope you enjoy the rodeo!